# How to give client mac for BOOTP, in DHCP scapy?

Tags: python, scapy, dhcp, bootp

clientMac = "00:00:01:00:11:03"
    bootp    = BOOTP(op = opcode,chaddr = clientMac, ciaddr = "0.0.0.0",xid =  0x01020304,flags= 0x8000)

Here, I try to create bootp part for a DHCP offer packet. But in the packet capture, the clientMac is shown as 30 30 3a 30 30 3a. I get a junk mac address.
When I convert my original clientmac into ascii, its coming as 30 30 3a 30 30 3a.
ie,

```
      ASCII
: -> 3a (hex)
0 -> 30 (hex)
1 -> 31 (hex)
```

Here how to give clientMac for BOOTP(), in DHCP scapy?

Answer (score 1):

```
clientMac = binascii.unhexlify('000001001201')
```

This way, its worked.

Answer (score 0):

On BOOTP only (I assume for historical reasons), you need to pass the raw MAC value to chafe rather than the literal one.

Use `clientMac = str2mac("...")`